# How to append to end of each line in a file, without merging or replacing with next lines in a file?

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

```
    package bufferedInputStream;


    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.RandomAccessFile;


    public class IsAvailable {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            File files = new File("D:\\eclipse\\Files");

            File[] f = files.listFiles();


            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f[0], "rw");

            String s = raf.readLine();




            while(s!=null) {



                if(s.contains("Hello")) {
                    raf.seek(s.length());
                    raf.write((s + " @ignore").getBytes());

                }
                s = raf.readLine();

            }

            raf.close();

        }
    }
```

I need to add @ignore string at the end of each line which contains the String Hello

Input file(.txt file) Content:

Hello Madam
Cool
Baby Cool
Hey Hello

==============================================

Expected output

Hello Madam @ignore
Cool
Baby Cool
Hey Hello @ignore

Actual output:

HelloHello @ignoreey ey Hello @ignoreHello @ignore

Comment: Please help to solve this problem

Comment: You can’t. Rewrite the file.

Comment: So rewrite the file and rename the file right?